# When is a line integral of a holomorphic function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a connected open set, $z_0 \in U$, and $g$ holomorphic on $U$.  I know that if $U$ is simply connected, then $$G(z) := \int_{z_0}^z g(w)dw$$ is holomorphic on $U$, and $G'(z) = g(z)$.  Here the path from $z_0$ to $z$ doesn't matter.

On the other hand, suppose $U$ has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$, so e.g. $U$ is an annulus about $0$.  Here I would want to always assume a path from $z_0$ to $z$ has winding number $0$ about $0$.  In that case, $G(z)$ seems well defined.  Is it continuous?  Holomorphic?

Comment: When the integral of $g$ over any closed curve in $U$ is $0$.

Comment: $G(z)$ may not be well defined, as in the case $U = \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ and $g(z) = \frac{1}{z}$